# Use of unresolved identifier 'CoreMLDelegate' - TFLite

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow2.0, coreml, tensorflow-lite

I am using https://github.com/sunkeunchoi/posenet-ios to play around with PoseNet and TensorFlowLite, but I keep getting a build fail message when I try to run it: Use of unresolved identifier 'CoreMLDelegate' for `CoreMLDelegate()` (see code below).
I did not change anything from the code after downloading it.
When I commented out the CoreMLDelegate() swift, the app started working but I would like to solve the issue. 
Could you try to download it and see if you have the same problem as me ?

````
    switch delegate {
    case .Metal:
      delegates = [MetalDelegate()]
    case .CoreML:
        if let coreMLDelegate = CoreMLDelegate() {
        delegates = [coreMLDelegate]
      } else {
        delegates = nil
      }
    default:
      delegates = nil
    }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are looking at a user fork of the official PoseNet example app.

Please use the official version, which can be found here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/posenet/ios

You can clone the entire `tensorflow/examples` repository, run `pod install`, and open the `PoseNet.xcworkspace` to build the app.

```sh
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/examples
cd examples/lite/examples/posenet/ios
pod install --repo-update
open PoseNet.xcworkspace   # This should open your Xcode.
```